# PrestaShop: add javascript array elements using smarty

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty, element, prestashop

I am trying to figure out way to add array elements from *.tpl files in PrestaShop.

What I have is js variable:

```
var combinations = [];
```

What I need is to add elements to this array, from *.tpl file.
I have available $combinations array of items, arrays, arrays of arrays etc., with keys assigned - so imploding makes no point.

I am trying something like:

```
{addJsDef combinations[]=$combinations} but it of course won't work.
```

Since PS documentation is worse than poor, I guess it's just guessing day, but maybe someone has experienced similar problems...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, if in PHP you assign to Smarty elements like this:

```
$smarty->assign('combinations', array (1,2,3,20));
```

you can use in Smarty:

```
<script>
    var combinations = [];
    {foreach $combinations as $item}
    combinations.push({$item})
    {/foreach}
    console.log(combinations);
</script>
```

As I added `console.log(combinations);` to log to JS console, in console there is

```
Array [ 1, 2, 3, 20 ]
```

so all elements were inserted into JavaScript array.

In case you have more complex PHP array:

```
$smarty->assign('combinations', array(
        'a' => 'aval',
        'b' => 'bval',
        'c' => array('c1' => 'c1val', 'c2' => 'c2val'),
        'd' => array(
            'd1' => 'd1val',
            'd2' => array(
                'd2‌​1' => 'd21val',
                'd22'   => 'd22val',
                'd23'   => array('d231', 'd232')
            )
        )
    ));
```

and you want create flat JavaScript array you may use:

```
{function jsadd}
    {foreach $data as $item}
        {if not $item|@is_array}
            combinations.push('{$item}')
        {else}
            {jsadd data = $item}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/function}

<script>
    var combinations = [];
    {jsadd data=$combinations}
    console.log(combinations);
</script>
```

and you will get:

```
Array [ "aval", "bval", "c1val", "c2val", "d1val", "d21val", "d22val", "d231", "d232" ]
```

**EDIT2**

And if you need to create multidimensional array in JavaScript using data from PHP as you explained in comment you can use this Smarty template:

```
{function jsadd keypart=''}
    {foreach $data as $key => $item}
        {if not $item|@is_array}
            {if $keypart eq ''}
                combinations['{$key}'] = '{$item}'
             {else}
                combinations{$keypart}['{$key}'] = '{$item}'
            {/if}
        {else}
            combinations{$keypart}['{$key}'] = [];
            {jsadd data = $item keypart = "`$keypart`['`$key`']" }
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/function}

<script>
    var combinations = [];
    {jsadd data=$combinations}
    console.log(combinations['a']);
</script>
```

Comment: "I have available $combinations array of items, arrays, arrays of arrays etc."

So, lets say in PHP I may use:
$smarty->assign('combinations', array('a'=>'aval', 'b'=>'bval', 'c'=>array('c1'=>'c1val','c2'=>'c2val'),'d'=>array('d1'=>'d1val','d2'=>array('d21'=>'d21val','d22'=>'d22val','d23'=>array('d231','d232')))))

Comment: @KubaStachu And what should JavaScript array contain for those PHP values? Please edit your question with those sample data and desired JS array output for it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't need to flatten the array, I need to duplicate it's structure for javascript. Actually I am fighting with static variables in prestashop module, but they just seem not working in PrestaShop...

Comment: OK, I solved the problem with static vars, which turned out to be problem with php's array_merge(), I'll post solution in a few days when I get whole module to work.

Comment: @KubaStachu I've added solution how to create multidimensional array in Javascript from PHP data as you requested. I don't think you should put your solution here because you asked how to create JavaScript array from PHP data in Smarty and not how to do it using other method.